# change behavior of tomcat when page not found (404)

Tags: angular, tomcat, http-status-code-404

Can anyone give an advice on how to configure Tomcat in order to complitely avoid 404, and instead when page is not found (particularly in cases when 404 should be triggered) return index.html content and 200 as a status?
Let me give you why do I want to do that:

1. We have angular application "www.app.exmpl/app", when user hits "www.app.exmpl/app" application displayed properly and 200 returned. index.html returned which has angular application code.
2. When user hits "www.app.exmpl/app/some_unexisted_url_in_file_system_path" tomcat tries to find endpoint or html file which could serve this url, and returns 404, and in web.xml we have this configuration:

   ```
   <error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/index.html</location>
   </error-page>
   ```

which leads user to 404 response, but still web app gets load
properly since index.html has angular app in it and after load page
rewrites url to proper one like: "www.app.exmpl/app".

3. When user hits "www.app.exmpl/app/url_handled_by_angular_app", then still page OR endpoint under "url_handled_by_angular_app" has not found, so tomcat sets code to 404 and renders index.html, which gets back to the user, and on user's pc this response renders as angular app without url rewriting since angular app knows how to handle this "url_handled_by_angular_app" route.

So all in all I need just to get rid of 404 and replace them all with 200 and just render index.html content in such cases. What is the best practise for this situation?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Can you provide more details about the your `Routing Strategy`.
Well I yhink you have to use this `{useHash: true}`

This might be a case ,if you have not used  `{useHash: true}` and when you are reloading it search for the particular file which is in URL path,
You can find more here  https://thinkster.io/tutorials/angular-2-routing-navigation

Comment: How will it fix 404 at tomcat?

Comment: @Pavel Please share your routing file content.

Comment: Actually you are right, to use HashLocationStrategy is the best practice. Thank you.

Comment: PathLocationStrategy is preferred over HashLocationStrategy. Ref [angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/router#which-strategy-is-best)

Answer (score 4):

The application deep links will not work without the redirect rule on the server. All the deep links have to redirect to the application `index.html` by the server.

To setup the tomcat to redirect any deep links -

1. Configure the RewriteValve in server.xml
2. Write the rewrite rule in rewrite.config

**1. Configure the RewriteValve in server.xml**

Edit the ~/conf/server.xml to add the below Valve inside the Host section as below –

```
...
      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve" />

...
      </Host>
...
```

**2. Write the rewrite rule in rewrite.config**

Create directory structure – ~/conf/Catalina/localhost/ and create the rewrite.config file inside it with the below content. Note - here I am considering `/app` as the context path of the application as mentioned in the question.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_PATH} !-f
RewriteRule ^/app/(.*) /app/index.html
```

After setting this up restart the tomcat server and you can hit the deep links of the application which will route to the correct components inside the angular application.

You can refer to [this post](http://codedumpster.nithinbiliya.com/deep-linking-issue-angular-application-tomcat-server/) for more details.

Comment: Wow. Thank you for detailed explanation. :) It is kind of a hard way... Do not think it should be used in order to resolve the issue I had...

Comment: for your point 3 - when user hits URL `www.app.exmpl/app/url_handled_by_angular_app`, you want the server to return `index.html`. This is set by the rewrite rule which says if the URL contains anything with context path `/app/*`, then return index.html. From there angular routing will take over and return the corresponding component for that path.

Answer (score 0):

When an error page is not a static one, but a JSP page (or a Servlet), it can change response status (`response.setStatus(200)`) and serve the static file (forwarding to it or including it).

Though I guess that in an use case like your one it would be more appropriate to use a `302` (client redirect) response, like `response.sendRedirect(application.getContextPath() + "/index.html")`.

Comment: Redirect all “virtual” url’s to index.html will make angular app work improperly, since it will make impossible to handle routes served by angular, since routes will be cut out during redirection. Abhishek provided correct solution to subject of this thread, other solution is to map url pattern of the application to render index.html without url rewriting, which will make routes handling possible. But I am personally like HashLocationStrategy better, since it let me avoid unnecessary server side configuration with mapping.